# Create a custom album in the Android Gallery App

Tags: android, image, gallery, android-contentprovider

I want create a new 'album' in Android.  I unserstood that you have to do it with your own ContentProvider.  But i can't figure out how.  If you take pictures, all the images appear in the album 'Camera'.  If you have installed Google+ you'll see 2 extra albums: Instant Upload & Profile Picture.

We want to create something similar.  We have an album per user online and we want that it appears as an album item in the Gallery app.  Can someone point me in the right direction.

I already checked: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Actually im not really sure if it is possible.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this way to create album in Gallery app. The name appears as 'app images'.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File dir = new File(path, "/appname/media/app images/");
if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
}

File file = new File(dir, filename + ".jpg");
String imagePath =  file.getAbsolutePath();
    //scan the image so show up in album
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
        new String[] { imagePath }, null,
        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        if(Config.LOG_DEBUG_ENABLED) {
            Log.d(Config.LOGTAG, "scanned : " + path);
        }
        }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Angelokh the solution you have provided was working fine. But i have one issue. The images with .png are showing in gallery. If rename the .png file to .jpg then they are showing in gallery. Is there any thing we can do in code to resolve this issue or it is by default behaviour of gallery app ?