# Android How to create new photo album and add it to default phone gallery in Code

Tags: android, android-camera, photo-gallery, android-photos

I have an app, let's call it FilterAppX
it basically let's you load an image, and I will customize it, say by adding a flower to it, or some silly items.

Now after processing the image, I will save it.
I want to be able to create a photo album to the default Gallery app that comes with all the android phones, so for Galaxy S2 for instance, there is an app (not dowloaded from appStore, it comes with the phone) called "Gallery", which it lets you choose many different images that you took with the phone, either from the camera just now, or screen capture, or whatever

so something like the screen shot below
[image]

so as you can see, this is a screen shot from default android phone on galaxy s2

i have downloaded some other apps, and it creates its own album that has the app's name, so i know it is possible and i am trying to do the same thing
basically i want a folder called "FilterAppX" which has the pictures taken by my map

how can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a custom album in the Android Gallery App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683259/create-a-custom-album-in-the-android-gallery-app)

Answer (score 0):

you just make your own folder that has photos made by "FilterAppX".

In case of you, the directory is "~/sdcards/FilterAppX".